# Ajax to MVC controller. Not passing parameters unless Ajax followed by alert

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have the strangest situation. I have two ajax POST. First I had problems passing the parameters to the controller but at some point I got them trough and with some debugging I figured out that I only get all of the values to the controller if my ajax definition is followed by an alert.

One of them:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Contact/IntresseAnmälan/',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        Namn: $('#namn').val(),
        Mail: $('#mail').val(),
        Info: $('#meddelande').val(),
        Telefon: $('#nr').val(),
        IsEnkel: false,
        PassId: function () {
            var url = window.location.pathname;
            var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            return id;
        },
        Participanter: getParticipant(),
        ParticipantMail: getParticipantMail()
    },
    traditional: true,
    success: function (result) {
       // window.location.href = '@Url.Action("IntresseAnmälan", "Contact")';
    }
});
alert("Hur sparas dina uppgifter?");
```

Here are my Getters for name and mail. The form-elements(input type mail and text) theese are dynamicly added to the form if the user wants clicks a button two inputs are added. Then theese functions returns an array with the inputed values from the form.

```
    function getParticipant() {
    var p = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= participantCount; i++) {
        var name = '#anNamn' + i;
        p[i -1] = $(name).val()
    }

    return p; 
}

function getParticipantMail() {
    var p = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= participantCount; i++) {
        p[i -1] = $('#anMail' + i).val();
    }

    return p;
}
```

And here is my controller. I've removed the body in the controller. It saves to the Db and send a verification mail to the admin.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult IntresseAnmälan(BokningContainer bokning)
    {
     //Saves to Db and Send a verification mail to admin

    }
```

If I exclude the alert after the ajax some parameters are passed, I think it's `Namn` and `Mail`, but most of them not passed. I'm quite puzzled.

Also, is ajax the only way to pass an object to a controller from jQuery?

Comment: what is `getParticipant` and `getParticipantMail` are they asynchronous functions

Comment: can you provide your controller action code ?

Comment: I think you trapped in a non-blocking issue. Let us see the getParticipant and getParticipantMail implementations.

Comment: I've added the definition fow the getters of mail and name.

Comment: In my other ajax definition I don't have the get functions but I still have the same situation.

Comment: You should provide your data before ajax call. Make an array of data and then send it via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, is ajax the only way to pass an object to a controller from
>   jQuery?

No, you can use a regular [HTML Form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) to submit your data, you just have to conform to the expected object in the controller `Action` (should be decorated with `HttpPostAttribute`) - There is a Model-Binding process which attempting to bind the `Request` data to your domain object.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that i want to pass arrays of strings. If I just define variables with the same name as in the form it works but the problem is that parts of the form are dynamicly added and the id:s of some of the form elements are not static. So I need to use javascript funcitons to create an array and put it in an object. But i'm wondering if there is any other way of passing that custom object to the controller with the definition as described above.(i've tried using params but it didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass every field's value using jQuery. Instead you can create a form whose data you want to post like :

```
<form id="frmTest">
... add input types here
</form>
```

and you can pass data of form using $('#frmTest').serialize() method to the controller

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#frmTest').serialize(),
            url: "url",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) { alert('worked!'); },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
```